# Form 1065, where do I put business expenses?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, partnership

I have the following type of expenses:

- PO box
- Business application and formation fees
- Paypal fees

How do I list these in my 1065? Are these considered cost of goods sold or under other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PO Box you'll probably report it on line 20 as "other deductions".

For Paypal fees - if those are deducted directly from the transactions then they just reduce gross receipts, otherwise - also line 20.

Business application and formation costs are considered "startup costs" and there are specific rules for them:

- Only up to $5000 of startup costs can be deducted (again - line 20)
- If your startup costs are more than $50K, the excess reduces the deduction (i.e.: if your startup costs are $55K and more - you can deduct nothing)
- Startup costs you cannot deduct are amortized over the period of 15 years.

See [Publication 535](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p535#en_US_2020_publink1000208919) on start up costs.